# How to catch universal links after redirection?

Tags: ios

The point is that I corectly set up universal links for my domain: `example.com`. And if within other or system app I tap on the link:

`http://www.example.com/first/second` then my app is being opened:) it just works.

But my links are linked to other domain `otherdomain.com` which redirects to `example.com`. And it is not going to work. What is the way to workaround this?

**Is it possible to make it working withount removing redirection?**

Comment: Any ideas?:) same problem, trying to workaround...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS considers what to do **immediately** after a link is tapped. If app exists, and the domain allow associated app to be opened via link, the app is being opened. **There is no way to catch redirection.**

First direct link is considered as not to be opened via app, and iOS **does not track** what is going on later. **It doesnt care about redirections in context of universal links.**